# Unity game campaign installs on Android not tracked in Facebook Analytics for Apps

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-analytics

I'm observing a large difference in tracking campaign installations between Android and iOS. Analytics for Apps show about 1000 installs on iOS and just 5 on Android (which correlates to the number of developer installations of the game). I'm cross-checking in Game Analytics and Google Developer console and I can see that there are much more Android players than reported by install tracking (and they're not organic players).

I've integrated Facebook SDK for Unity as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted), with a standard activation procedure described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples):

```
void Awake() {
    if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
        FB.Init(() => {
            FB.ActivateApp();
        });
    } else {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}

void OnApplicationPause(bool pause) {
    if (!pause) {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}
```

The Facebook application created for this project has been reviewed and approved by Facebook team. Is there anything that I'm not aware of that would prevent campaing installs from being tracked properly by Facebook SDK for Unity on Android?

Comment: Which version of the facebook sdk have you used? also [take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18879760/2030635)

Comment: I'm using Unity Facebook SDK 7.9.0. I have Debug Android Key Hash added in the Facebook application configuration.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  using Facebook.Unity;

  void Awake ()
  {
  if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
    FB.Init(InitCallback);
  } else {
    FB.ActivateApp();
  }
 }

 private void InitCallback ()
 {
  if (FB.IsInitialized) {
    FB.ActivateApp();
 } else {
    Debug.Log("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
 }
}
```